# Dagger 2 unable to do constructor injection

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have an app with activities and fragments with dependencies injected via dagger 2
I am able to do field injection in activities and fragments but not able to do constructor injection in other classes.
Here's my relevant code

```
@Module
public abstract class MainFragmentProvider {
  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = HomeFragmentModule.class)
  abstract HomeFragment provideHomeFragmentFactory();
}
```

and

```
@Module
public class HomeFragmentModule {
...
@Provides
 static HomePresenter provideHomePresenter(HomeView homeView, HomeInteractor homeInteractor) {
    return new HomePresenter(homeView, homeInteractor);
 }
```

How can I write code so that I can get dependencies directly in HomePresenter by constructor injection instead of writing provideMethods in module. I am doing this because every time I want to change the constructor arguments in this case, I need to change the module code as well.

How can I do something like this in HomePresenter's constructor?

```
@Inject
public HomePresenter(HomeView homeView, HomeInteractor homeInteractor) {

    this.homeInteractor = homeInteractor;
    this.homeView = homeView;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To inject constructor, Dagger has to know where to get parameters passed to it i.e.
you have to provide 
`HomeView homeView, HomeInteractor homeInteractor`

So create also methods for providing other dependencies:

```
@Provides
 static HomeView provideHomeView() {
    return ...
 }

@Provides
 static HomeInteractor provideHomeInteractor() {
    return ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the android extensions for dagger 2 but as far as I know there are two ways to achieve the result you are looking for.

In the relevant component you can specify a method with your type:

```
interface SomeComponent {
  HomePresenter presenter(); // Method name does not matter here, only the type
}
```

and access it like this

```
class Home {
  HomePresenter presenter;

  void initialize() { //This could be your onCreate or wherever you typically inject
    presenter = getSomeComponent().presenter();
  }
}
```

or you can request it if you specify an inject method for your Home object:

```
interface SomeComponent {
  void inject(Home home);
}

class Home {
  @Inject HomePresenter presenter;

  void initialize(){
    getSomeComponent().inject(this);
  }
}
```

In both cases you must ensure your `Component` includes the appropriate `Module`s.